# Unable to generate a Nuget Package in VSTS Build

Tags: nuget, .net-core, azure-devops

I have a dotnet core library that I'm trying to publish to my VSTS hosted Nuget feed. I have a problem in that it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The build is completing without errors but the nupkg file seems to be neither created nor pushed. The build log below contains an error as I am trying to publish the output as a build asset but there is no output to publish...

(log start cut off for brevity)

```
******************************************************************************
Starting: NuGet pack
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
Version      : 2.0.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================
Downloading: https://dist.nuget.org/win-x86-commandline/v4.0.0/nuget.exe
Caching tool: NuGet 4.0.0 x64
Using version: 4.0.0
Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.0.0 x64
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
******************************************************************************
Finishing: NuGet pack
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: NuGet push
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : NuGet
Description  : Restore, pack, or push NuGet packages, or run a NuGet command. Supports NuGet.org and authenticated feeds like Package Management and MyGet.
Version      : 2.0.3
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613747)
==============================================================================
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
******************************************************************************
Finishing: NuGet push
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: Publish Artifact: Nuget Packages
******************************************************************************
==============================================================================
Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
Description  : Publish Build artifacts to the server or a file share
Version      : 1.0.42
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
==============================================================================
Publish build artifacts failed with error: Not found PathtoPublish: d:\a\1\a\*.nupkg
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Publish Artifact: Nuget Packages
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Starting: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************
Cleaning any cached credential from repository: Esoterix (Git)
git remote set-url origin https://esoterix.visualstudio.com/_git/Esoterix
git remote set-url --push origin https://esoterix.visualstudio.com/_git/Esoterix
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Post Job Cleanup
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
Finishing: Build
******************************************************************************
```

The library is a .net core library using .NetCoreApp 1.1

The build definition follows a successful dotnet test run with...

NUGET PACK

Path to files to pack: **/src/*.csproj

Config: $(BuildConfiguration)

Package Folder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

NUGET PUSH

Path to packages to push: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg

Target Feed: local (my VSTS Package Feed)

This seems rather odd...

```
C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001
Active code page: 65001
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .NET core library project, and `.csproj` file usually exist in `**/src/ProjectName/ProjectName.csproj`.

So please check the **Path to csproj or nuspec file(s) to pack** in **Nuget pack** step, it mainly should be `**/src/ProjectName/*.csproj` or `**/src/*/*.csproj`. Or if you only have one project, you can use `**/*.csproj` directly.

Comment: Indeed - This could be a case of 'BrainMissingException'. I will confirm when I get back in l.